# Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Test String -

> COAW983742892 COBW98374289

Regular Expression -

```
^(COBW|COaW|COXW)[0-9]+
```

Matching String is -

> COAW983742892

My question is , why it don't match the both strings?

Comment: Your regex engine probably either returns on the first match or you only check for the first match. Without knowing what enginge you use and how you check the results, this cannot be answered.

Comment: Or your regex engine is case-sensitive.

Comment: `COBW\d+|COAW\d+|COXW\d+`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex suggests that it should be the start of the String with `^` symbol at the start of regex.

Try this regex -

```
(COBW|COAW|COXW)[0-9]+
```

It will match both the strings.

Answer (score 0):

You started your regex from `^` (the start of the string), so the only content
likely to be matched is the **initial part** of your source string.

Remove the starting `^` from the regex and it will match both substrings.

I assume that:

- you use `g` option,
- the true content of your regex is CO**A**W (you changed `A` into `a` by mistake),
  otherwise set `i` option.